# What are the requirements for gradle.kts generated by spring initializr?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, spring-initializr

I modified the build.gradle file of the newly created gradle project named build.gradle.kts, and then copied the build.gradle.kts content of the demo project generated by spring initializr, and then build, this file reported a lot of errors, but spring initializr project can be built correctly.

The two build.gradle.kts are exactly the same. What's wrong?

This is the wrong screenshot https://s2.ax1x.com/2019/08/21/mNvASA.png

This is the correct screenshot https://s2.ax1x.com/2019/08/21/mNvEQI.png

This is the content

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.7.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off an on again? That is, have you tried `Gradle → Reimport All Gradle Projects`, or perhaps `File → Invalidate Caches / Restart...`?

Comment: I have restarted it many times and tried what you said, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Check the Gradle wrapper version in both projects: `./gradlew -v` (or `gradlew.bat -v` on Windows). And also make sure that you IDE uses gradle wrapper instead of installation of Gradle.